# ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I've trying to set a variable depending on the an input variable.

`$inputs->page` may not exist.

```
$variables->page = ($inputs->page ? $inputs->page : $variables->page);
```

I thought that this shorthand says:

"If `$inputs->page` exists then assign `$variables-page` to this variable, otherwise keep it as `$variables->page`". But it seems that it's throwing the error because `$inputs->page` doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The shorthand says if `$inputs->page` is true then.. Change it using `isset($inputs->page)` or `!is_null($inputs->page)` or `!empty($inputs->page)` depending your case

Comment: Thanks, if you write it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shorthand says if `$inputs->page` is `true` then..

You have to change it using `isset($inputs->page)` or `!is_null($inputs->page)` or `!empty($inputs->page)` depending your case